# WordPress Rewrite rule with custom query var

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to make a custom rewrite rule 
the url is `my-domain.com/web-directory/?loc=/directory/listing/john-smith`
and I want to rewrite to `my-domain.com/web-directory/directory/listing/john-smith`.

I need `$_GET['loc']='/directory/listing/john-smith';`

made a try with this function but did not work

```
function custom_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'loc';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );

function custom_setup_rewrites(){
add_rewrite_rule('^web-directory\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)$','index.php?pagename=web-directory&loc=/$matches[1]/$matches[2]/$matches[3]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_setup_rewrites' );
```

Any help please !

Comment: Note that WordPress query vars don't end up in `$_GET`. If your code is expecting the value in `$_GET`, you will need to set it yourself via `get_query_var`.

Comment: Yes I use `$loc=get_query_var( 'loc');`  and the output for `$loc`  that I receive is just "directory"

Comment: Forgot to flush the rewrite rules :) after that the code working fine!